# How to get SelectList to honor DisplayName annotation with enums?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, enums, data-annotations

I am using enums in my ViewModels to populate a `DropDownListFor` like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedDropDownValue, 
       new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(SearchOptions)), SearchOptions.SSN))
```

This works well. However, I would like to display the `DisplayName` property of the `DisplayNameAttribute` that is associated with each value within the enum.

I have search Stackoverflow and seen a number of ways to do this with helpers, extensions, etc. Is it possible to, within a single statement like this, easily tell the `SelectList` to use the `DisplayNameAttribute`?

I'm thinking something like:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedDropDownValue, 
                      new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(SearchOptions), 
                      "Value", GetDisplayAnnotation()), SearchOptions.SSN))
```

Comment: There is no built in way to do this. You need to use/write helpers, extensions, etc. as you've seen in other posts.

Comment: I don't think so, but why don't you just simply write a method which takes an enum, extracts the DisplayName annotations and returns a SelectList?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written some code that does the same thing except it looks for the `DescriptionAttribute`.

Modified for your situation it looks like this:

```
public static string GetDescription(this Enum value)
{
    if (value == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("value");        

    var attribute = value.GetType()
        .GetField(value.ToString())
        .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayNameAttribute), false)
        .Cast<DisplayNameAttribute>()
        .FirstOrDefault();

    return attribute == null ? value.ToString() : attribute.DisplayName;
}
```

Rather than create a select list and call the `@Html.DropDownList` in my view, I have created editor and display templates that look a bit like this (Called Enum.cshtml):

```
var values = Enum.GetValues(enumType)
    .Cast<Enum>()
    .Select(v => new SelectListItem
    {
        Selected = v.Equals(Model),
        Text = v.GetDescription(),
        Value = v.ToString(),
    });

Html.DropDownList("", values)
```

I then decorate any enum properties in my ViewModels with the UIHint attribute and any enum properties use the above code automatically.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [UIHint("Enum")]
    public MyEnumType MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

There are a couple of edge cases to look out for such as handling null values, nullable types and adding a default entry to the drop down but this should give you the bare bones to get started.