# how i can create enum with few values for element?

Tags: c#

How i can create *enum* with few values for element, something `like` this:

```
enum SomeEnum
{
A = {"value1", "value2"},
B = {"value1", "value2"},
C = {"value1", "value2", "value3"}
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a dictionary not an enum.

Comment: Short answer: you can't.

Comment: It might be possible with the use of attributes and extensions: [Multiple enum descriptions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32901771/multiple-enum-descriptions) or [Enum with multiple descriptions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18534424/enum-with-multiple-descriptions)

Comment: What is the purpose of such an enum or its *emulation*? What do you expect to have on, say, `SomeEnum.B`?

Comment: I think you want a class that has an enum property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so i find solution

```
public static class Enums
    {
        public enum A
        {
            first,
            second
        }
        public enum B
        {
            first,
            second,
            third
        }
    }
```

thanks to all)